# Log4j Logging Based on Class

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to do logging based on class. I created something like this:

```
log4j.appender.cancellation=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cancellation.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.cancellation.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.cancellation.File=/logs/cancellation.log
log4j.appender.cancellation.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cancellation.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.mydomain.bean.CancellationBean=cancellation
```

and on my class:

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.mydomain.bean.CancellationBean");
```

but it doesn't work, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion though:

```
log4j.logger.com.mydomain.bean.CancellationBean=DEBUG, cancellation
```